# Cannot handover value from Activity to Repository to pass it into Dao method

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room, setter

I have a vocabulary room-database where words are divided into 4 categories (indicated in respective field of the table).

When the Activity launches, the method `getWords()` from Dao is triggered with the required argument being passed by `WorkActivity`

On launching the Activity I get the following error

```
Cannot create an instance of class space.rodionov.englishwanker.WordViewModel.
```

Where did I go wrong? Any help is appreciated

In Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE category IN(:filterCategory) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4")
    Single<List<Word>> get4words(List<Integer> filterCategory);
```

In Repository:

```
public class WordRepository {
    private ArrayList<Integer> categoryFilter;
    private WordDao mWordDao;   
    //other variables
    WordRepository(Application application) {
        WordDatabase db = WordDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mWordDao = db.WordDao();
        clearFilter();
        setFilter(categoryFilter);
        m4words = mWordDao.get4words(categoryFilter);
    }
    public void clearFilter(){
        categoryFilter.clear();
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<Integer> categoryFilter) {
        this.categoryFilter = categoryFilter;
    }
```

In ViewModel:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> categoryFilter = new ArrayList<>();
private WordRepository mRepository;
// declaring variables
public WordViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
    //declaring
    mRepository.setFilter(categoryFilter);
    m4words = mRepository.get4words();
}
public void clearFilter() {
    categoryFilter.clear();
}
public void setFilter(ArrayList<Integer> categoryFilter) {
    this.categoryFilter = categoryFilter;
}
//other methods
```

In WorkActivity:

```
private WordViewModel wordViewModel;
public ArrayList<Integer> categoryFilter = new ArrayList<>();
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean category0 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category0", true);
        boolean category1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Category1", true);
        //other catigories from memory ... 
        //
        wordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication()))
            .get(WordViewModel.class);
        wordViewModel.getListLivedata().observe(this, words -> {
            adapter.submitList(words);
        });
        //
        wordViewModel.clearFilter();
        if (category0 == true) {
            categoryFilter.add(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: common_words added: called");
        }
        //other categories
        wordViewModel.setFilter(categoryFilter);
        //other methods
        //buildRecyclreVeiw
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is I just forgot to initialize `ArrayList categoryFilter` in Repository.